# Prove that if $m = 1 \pmod {\varphi (n)}$ and $(a, n) = 1$ then $a^{m} = a \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $m = 1 \pmod {\varphi (n)}$  and $(a, n) = 1$  then  $a^{m} = a \pmod n$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's function

Answer (score 4):

Well, since $(a, n) = 1$, [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) tells you that $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, and $m \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ means that $m = 1 + t \varphi(n)$ for some $t$, so...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ \color{#C00}{a^\varphi\equiv 1}\:\Rightarrow\: a^{1 + n\varphi} = a\, (\color{#C00}{a^\varphi})^n\equiv\, a({\color{#C00}1})^n\equiv\, a.\ $ Similarly $\rm\, a^k\equiv a^{(k\ mod\ \varphi)}$

**Remark** $\ $ The proof uses only the *associativity* of multiplication, and the *neutral property* of $\,1,\,$ hence it is valid for any binary operation having these properties, i.e. it is true in any monoid.